# Google Sheets - conditional formatting self-referencing

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm building a calendar document, which has a grid on the left with calendar days (columns A:G), and then a list on the right hand side with details as to what's happening on those days (starting in I). When an item in the list corresponds to a day on the left, I want to colour that day. It's based on a very slightly modified version of this template: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mbxsHjsodBng9tO4_6LaJ73k6Bm-G45DGB_Yc3rWrmo/edit#gid=0

I've got as far as applying `=COUNTIF(I2:I,A3)>0` as a custom formula to A3, which correctly colours A3 if there is anything in column I that matches the content of A3. What I would like to do is apply that to the entire range A3:G7 based on whichever value is present in each individual cells. It feels like there should be a way to do this without having to set up this formula 365 times across my sheet, but everything that gets close doesn't seem to apply across the range like I expect.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to account of the month is being considered I stablished that every 9 rows there would be a new month. Then you can set this formula in range A1:G:

> ```
> =countif($I:$I,date(2022,roundup(row(A1)/9,0),A1))>0
> ```

[image]
Here you have the link to my spreadsheet copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IN_OCfd3lDQlniN_UTsO3puGWiWFuFejFxiTvUYrwq8/edit?usp=sharing